# JAGS error re length mismatch in Node

Tags: regression, logistic, bayesian, jags

I am trying to specify a logistic regression model in JAGS. I am encountering an error I haven't seen before, and haven't found a solution online. I would appreciate if anyone knew what was happening.

```
data<-read.csv("JAGSdata.csv",header=T) #read in csv file
N <-length(data$study) #number of obs.
M <-length(unique(data$study))
ls(data)

#input the data
Data <- list(
N = N,
synergy = data$synergy,
dapto   = data$dapto,
teic    = data$teic,
tela    = data$tela,
cph     = data$cph,
cpm     = data$cpm,
blfrac  = data$blfrac,
gpfrac  = data$gpfrac,
loglt6  = data$loglt6,
mrsa    = data$mrsa,
vssa    = data$vssa
)

#INITIAL VALUES FOR MCMC

#MODEL

model <- "
model{
#coefficient priors
#------------------------------------------------------------#

bcons   ~ dunif(-10,10)
bdapto  ~ dunif(-10,10)
bteic   ~ dunif(-10,10)
btela   ~ dunif(-10,10)
bcph    ~ dunif(-10,10)
bcpm    ~ dunif(-10,10)
blfrac  ~ dunif(-10,10)
bgpfrac ~ dunif(-10,10)
bloglt6 ~ dunif(-10,10)
bmrsa   ~ dunif(-10,10)
bvssa   ~ dunif(-10,10)

#Likelihood function
#-----------------------------------------------------------#

#N observations
for (i in 1:N) {
synergy[i] ~ dbern(p[i])
logit(p[i]) <- bcons + bdapto*dapto[i] + bteic*teic[i] + btela*tela[i] + 
               bcph*cph[i] + bcpm*cpm[i] + blfrac*blfrac[i] + 
               bgpfrac*gpfrac[i] + bloglt6*loglt6[i] + bmrsa*mrsa[i] + 
               bvssa*vssa[i]
}
}
"
writeLines(model, "model.txt")
model <- jags.model("model.txt", data=Data, n.chains=4, n.adapt=1000)
parameters<- c('bcons', 'bdapto', 'bteic','btela','bcph',
           'bcpm','blfrac','bgpfrac', 'bloglt6','bmrsa','bvssa')
start<-Sys.time()
update(model, 50000) # burn in
JAGS_samples <- coda.samples(model=model,variable.names=parameters,
                        n.iter=50000)
finish<-Sys.time()
finish-start
```

When I run this model I get the following error message:

```
Error in jags.model("model.txt", data = Data, n.chains = 4, n.adapt = 1000) : 
  Error in node dunif((-10),10)
Length mismatch in Node::setValue
```

Comment: I figured out my own issue! the variable blfrac had the same name as its coefficient and I think JAGS didnt like this.

When I changed it to belfrac*blfrac[i] and belfrac ~ dunif(-10,10), it ran fine.

Comment: You should answer your own question for people to see in the future! You can even select it as correct.